# Google sheet, IF cell greater than 0 True (Seems simple enough, but its not calculating)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[MY SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-a43L4AQGYWL89EjAP85B-NE5F2BjNFg-HdgjkYwS4/edit?usp=sharing)
The TIME CARD PAGE

In Column O, I have a formula that took me a while but is working.  The results of this formula are to return hours worked on a Sunday during 3rd shift hours.

If you look at the formula in cell O8

`=IF(COUNT(B8:C8)=2,IF(WEEKDAY(A8)=7,IF(U8=TRUE,(C8-"00:00:00")*24,"0.00"),"0.00"),"")`

It is currently returning 2.00

So to start off my double-time column (I) I was using a simple if condition, yet for some reason, it is not letting me grab that number.

`=IF(O8>0, "Yes", "No")`

I have tried with a 1, I have tried greater than or equal to, I have tried `(--"0.00")` I have tried multiple ways but as soon as I apply this to all the cells in that column it's just not working...

Is it the way I return the results on O8?  Am I just not doing something right with my IF condition, I'm at a total loss...

Comment: May I clarify what you want to do? You want to implement a formula in column I? One that reutrns you "true" if the values in column O are bigger then 0? And false otherwise?

Comment: Because of the quotation marks you use in the formula in column O the output is returned as a string. So you'll need to convert those to number. So in I3 =IF(O3+0>=1,"Yes","No") will return 'No'.

Comment: zig, yes. JPV, sounds like an answer to me =) post it up, and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your values in column O to an integer number.

For this you can use the [`Int()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490?hl=en) function:

`=IF(Int(O8)>0,TRUE,FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you zig, now i have a bunch more of complex formulas to figure out =)

Answer (score 1):

use this in **`I3`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(O3:O9*1>0, O3:O9, 
 IF(N3:N9*1>0, N3:N9, "0.00")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I like the idea of doing it in an array rather than every cell, although I do not understand the benefits of doing it this way VS. the way zig suggested.  I have however also used this method to figure out the overtime hours aswell by using ```=ARRAYFORMULA(G3:G9-I3:I9)``` in H3

Comment: there are several advantages using arrayformulas instead of per-row (per-cell) formulas. less formulas = less calculation time = better overall performance of your spreadsheet. example: let's say you have 4 columns with 1000 rows and in each cell there is one IF formula. in total that's 4000 formulas while you would need only 4 arrayformulas. that's **3996** formulas less

Comment: Thank you once again, I love learning this stuff =) my sheets coming a long way with your help.  I greatly appreciate your help along with this project.  I feel I'm coming a long way with it, and a lot of my formulas are pretty sloppy, but once I at least get everything working I will go back and simplify what I can, with what I've learned along the way =)